# Questions on "的话"

Tags: grammar, etymology

What is the etymology behind "的话" in the common construct `如果...的话` or `要是...的话`?

In addition to wondering about it's meaning, what exactly is the `的` doing? Is it modifying the `如果`? Is it modifying the phrase in between? Or is it somehow a possessive construct?

Any light you can shed on the subject would be appreciated.

(Note: I looked over [this question](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/836/why-does-the-construction-of-%E8%A6%81%E6%98%AF%E2%80%A6%E7%9A%84%E8%AF%9D-mean-if) but there is no real answer, accepted or otherwise.)

Comment: The answer by Lars Andren more or less explains what `的话` means in English. "If, say for example, blah blah blah..."

Comment: I would translate `如果...的话` as `if ... is the case`. I'm not very sure, but I guess in most cases we can leave `的话` out.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%9A%84%E8%AF%9D it is an optional particle, and may be used with or without 如果 or 要是.

Comment: I know the meaning and the usage. I just don't know why that's the meaning and usage. Take this example: `你想看的话...`. It translates to "If you want to watch..." but *literally* is, what, "You-want-to-watch type of words"? My best guess for meaning is "(In regards to) the words/case of you wanting to watch..." Does that sound right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it doesn't modify `如果` or the phrase in between, and there's nothing to do with possessive constructs. I wouldn't even notice it when I speak, but when I think about it, I agree with hrzhu, that it can be loosely translated to `is the case`, the actual words don't have explicit meaning here.

I think `的话` provides a short pause, which gives the speaker a chance to actually think about the condition or assumption being said. It sometimes creates a tension, e.g. `如果我杀了你的话...`, you can pause for many seconds here to frighten someone. Notice that `话` ends with the [a] vowel, so people tend to lengthen it when they don't know what to say, and need a sec to think, e.g. `如果他是GAY的话......他就不会喜欢你`.

So the idea is that with `的话`, the `如果` clause sounds more natural, because the condition or assumption being said does sometimes need a sec for you to pause and think. Without `的话`, it sounds quite abrupt, although it does work if you leave it out, in most cases. Personally I call these constructs the lubricant of the language.

Answer (score 1):

Just like @congusbongus said, it's used as an optional part of 如果. In case of 你想看的话, you can consider 的话 is introduced *implicitly* by 如果. The introducer itself is omitted. Really no magic here.

Comment: My question is not about its usage or meaning, but rather about the origin. I know how to use it and do frequently, with and without `如果`.