# At what situations should I leave out 话 in "~的话"

Tags: grammar

In the following sentence:

> 国籍的图片是来自于EmojiOne数据集，**有兴趣的**可以去看看了解一下。题目有奥运会奖牌，本次用国旗与国家联系起来。

This sentence seems to use "~的话，..." phrase, but omit the 话. (Let me know if I'm wrong but I proceed with the assumption that it is correct).

However, on these types of sentences I'm struggling to decide when to leave it in or out. How can I use them apart correctly? Is there any clue?

The above sentence should be fine if I rewrite it as following:

> 国籍的图片是来自于EmojiOne数据集，**你有兴趣的话就**可以去看看了解一下。题目有奥运会奖牌，本次用国旗与国家联系起来。

Or is it OK to *always* use the brief form as far as the meaning is clear enough in the context? I learned here that it is usually considered better to make the sentence simpler in Chinese, as far as it is clear...

---

#### NOTE

One of [the answer here](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/5525/questions-on-%E7%9A%84%E8%AF%9D) writes the following but my question is about 话, not 的话 (I agree without 的话 it sounds an incomplete sentence). Also my question doesn't necessarily indicate 如果 or 要是.

> Without 的话, it sounds quite abrupt, although it does work if you leave it out, in most cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This sentence seems to use "~的话，..." phrase, but omit the 话. (Let me know if I'm wrong but I proceed with the assumption that it is correct).

I think it omits 人 here; i.e. 有兴趣的 refers to 有兴趣的人 (people who are interested in). Using 人 makes the sentence more formal and polite, without it makes the sentence simpler and the meaning is still clear enough.

BTW [~的](http://www.zdic.net/z/1f/xs/7684.htm) is a common structure used instead of the referred people or things.

> 〈代〉 pron. 附着在词或短语之后,构成“的”字结构,代替所指的人或物。如:卖菜的;吃的

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! I know such usage of 的. But then regarding my original question, how should I use them apart?

Comment: @Blaszard Answer revised. Is that enough?

Comment: No, my question is, in this case 的 modifies 人 and not ~的话 structure, but in general if it is ~的话 structure, how can I use them apart? I would still like to know when I should leave 话 in and when out.

Comment: @Blaszard I can't think of any cases that it's ~的话 structure and 话 is omitted. I'll say that you'll always use 的话 explicitly when you intent to use the structure.

Comment: I see. I still feel I have seen such sentences, especially on the web (such as 知乎) but maybe it is my misunderstanding as well. Anyway when I encounter such case, I may ask again then.

Answer (score 1):

“有兴趣的” 代表 “有兴趣的人”。但是在这段话中，即使说“有兴趣的话”也说得通，但这里并不是这个意思。
Need to understand “……的话” means if...，比如：如果你能听懂的话，就很好- if this case, then what.. 如果……的话 is the structure

Comment: if you put 如果 at the beginning and it makes sense, it means if.. 如果读不通的话，就不是。